# (Laravel) How to filter table by newest pivot value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a table of orders (orders), a table of statuses (order_statuses) and a pivot table which is intended to be a status log (order_order_status).

When an order's status is changed, an entry is added to the pivot table.  The newest entry in the pivot table for that order will be it's current status.

I need to be able to display all orders which CURRENTLY have a given status.  For example, all orders in the 'Quote' status. Is there an eloquent way of building this query?

(EDIT, additional clarification: The CURRENT status of an order is the entry in the status log with the newest 'created_at' date.)

Here is some examples of the schemas:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = 2;
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | order_number | job_reference | accounting_reference | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  2 |      73 | 37-5         | Janis Joplin  | NULL                 | 2018-06-25 02:27:21 | 2018-06-25 02:27:21 |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM order_order_status WHERE order_id = 2 ORDER BY created_at;
+------+----------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | order_id | order_status_id | user_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+------+----------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    2 |        2 |               2 |     753 | 2012-06-27 09:47:00 | 2012-06-27 09:47:00 |
|    3 |        2 |               3 |     753 | 2012-06-27 09:56:00 | 2012-06-27 09:56:00 |
|    4 |        2 |               4 |     753 | 2012-06-27 09:56:00 | 2012-06-27 09:56:00 |
|    5 |        2 |               5 |    1153 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 |
|    6 |        2 |               6 |    1153 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 |
|    7 |        2 |              10 |    1153 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 |
|    8 |        2 |               7 |    1153 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 | 2012-06-27 10:13:00 |
|    9 |        2 |              10 |    1153 | 2012-06-27 10:42:00 | 2012-06-27 10:42:00 |
|   10 |        2 |               7 |    1153 | 2012-06-27 10:42:00 | 2012-06-27 10:42:00 |
|   11 |        2 |               8 |     753 | 2012-06-27 10:44:00 | 2012-06-27 10:44:00 |
|   12 |        2 |               9 |     753 | 2012-06-27 10:45:00 | 2012-06-27 10:45:00 |
| 2222 |        2 |              10 |      54 | 2013-01-03 12:08:00 | 2013-01-03 12:08:00 |
+------+----------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM order_statuses;
+----+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title          | tag            | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Archived Quote | archived_quote | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  2 | Quote          | quote          | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  3 | Order          | order          | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  4 | Confirmed      | confirmed      | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  5 | Manufacturing  | manufacturing  | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  6 | Painting       | painting       | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  7 | Dispatched     | dispatched     | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  8 | Invoiced       | invoiced       | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
|  9 | Paid           | paid           | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
| 10 | Closed         | closed         | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
| 11 | Archived       | archived       | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 | 2018-06-25 02:25:28 |
+----+----------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

EDIT: Further clarification.  THis is the SQL query which returns the required results.  I am looking for an eloquent method of getting the same results:

```
SELECT a.order_status_id, c.* 
FROM order_order_status a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, MAX(updated_at) last_date
    FROM order_order_status
    GROUP BY order_id
) b ON a.order_id = b.order_id AND a.updated_at = b.last_date 
INNER JOIN 
        orders c 
    ON c.id = a.order_id 
WHERE a.order_status_id = (SELECT id from order_statuses where tag="closed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [Join](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#joins). Eloquent creates two queries when fetching many to many relations. Can't use order by unfortunately in this case with eloquent.

**Update**

The query builder is going to be your best bet, unfortunately the accepted answer is going to be extremely inefficient and will not scale well to say the least. Off the top of my head the query would be something like:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
    ->leftJoin('order_order_status', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_order_status.order_id')
    ->leftJoin('order_statuses', function ($join) use ($title) {
         $join->on(
             'order_order_status.order_status_id',
             '=',
             DB::raw('SELECT id FROM order_statuses WHERE title = ' . $title . ' AND order_order_status.order_status_id = order_statuses.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1')
         );
    })
    ->select('orders.*')
    ->groupBy('orders.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the underlying problem. If no-one else comes up with an eloquent answer, I'll mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some relations in each model in order to join them

### orders

```
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class orders extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 't_orders';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    // join t_orders with t_order_order_status but get only the latest matching row out of order_order_status
    public function status_log()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\order_order_status', 'order_id','id')->orderBy('t_order_order_status.id', 'desc')->limit(1);
    }

}
```

### order_order_status

```
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class order_order_status extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 't_order_order_status';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    // join t_orders with t_order_order_status
    public function status_name()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\order_statuses', 'id','order_status_id');
    }

}
```

### order_statuses

```
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class order_statuses extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 't_order_statuses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

Then you would do something like this

```
App\Model\orders::with('status_log.status_name')->get();
```

Should get something like this

```
[  
   {  
      "id":2,
      "user_id":73,
      "order_number":"37-5",
      "job_reference":"Janis Joplin",
      "accounting_reference":null,
      "created_at":"2018-06-25 02:27:21",
      "updated_at":"2018-06-25 02:27:21",
      "status_log":[{  
        "id":4,
        "order_id":2,
        "order_status_id":4,
        "user_id":753,
        "created_at":"2012-06-27 09:56:00",
        "updated_at":"2012-06-27 09:56:00",
        "status_name":{  
           "id":4,
           "title":"Confirmed",
           "tag":"confirmed",
           "created_at":"2018-06-25 02:25:28",
           "updated_at":"2018-06-25 02:25:28"
        }
      }]
   }
]
```

Note I've prefixed table names with `t_` for readability but you can name them same as your models.

**UPDATE**

For that you can use something like this passing a clusre that will filter based on status id

```
$status = 3;

$result =  App\Model\orders::with(['status_log'=>function($query) use($status) {

    $query->where('t_order_order_status.order_status_id','=', $status);

    $query->with('status_name');

}])->get();

return $result;
```

Will give

```
[{  
      "id":2,
      "user_id":73,
      "order_number":"37-5",
      "job_reference":"Janis Joplin",
      "accounting_reference":null,
      "created_at":"2018-06-25 02:27:21",
      "updated_at":"2018-06-25 02:27:21",
      "status_log":[{                       // will be empty [] for order not in t_order_order_status
        "id":3,
        "order_id":2,
        "order_status_id":3,
        "user_id":753,
        "created_at":"2012-06-27 09:56:00",
        "updated_at":"2012-06-27 09:56:00",
        "status_name":{  
               "id":3,
               "title":"Order",
               "tag":"order",
               "created_at":"2018-06-25 02:25:28",
               "updated_at":"2018-06-25 02:25:28"
        }
     }]

   }]
```

It will return all orders but you can use `status_log` to figure out whether it has any record in `t_order_order_status` table , but in-case you want to remove the "extra" and retain just those orders which have are there in logger table then you might use filter on `$result`.

```
return $result->filter(function ($item) {
    return !empty($item->status_log && count($item->status_log));
});
```

Comment: Updated the clarification.

Comment: This solution works, but it is REALLY slow.  A query to filter a database of 7832 orders takes 763ms whereas the SQL quoted in the question only takes 55ms.  Nevertheless, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

> php artisan make:model User

in your User Model :

```
   protected $table='users';
   public $primaryKey='id';

 public function orders(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Orders','order_order_status','user_id','order_id')->orderby('created_at','desc');
 }
```

> php artisan make:model Order

in your Order Model :

```
  protected $table='orders';
  public $primaryKey='id';

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User','user_id');
  }

 public function order_status()
  {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\OrderStatus','order_order_status','order_id','order_status_id')->withTimestamps();
  }
```

> php artisan make:model OrderStatus

in your OrderStatus Model :

```
  protected $table='order_statuses';
  public $primaryKey='id';

 public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Order','order_order_status')->with('user')->orderBy('created_at','desc');
    }
```

> php artisan make:controller OrdersController

Now You want to get orders by OrderStatus title='Quote'

in your OrdersController :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;



 public function get_order(Request $request,$title){
         // $title='Quote';
         $orders=OrderStatus::where('title',$title)->with('orders')->get();
         return response()->json($orders);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the get_order function will return the orders which have had the status 'Quote' at any time, not the orders which have the status currently set to Quote

Comment: you need to pass different value on $title

Comment: check by passing static value to `$title='Confirmed'`

Comment: The title is not the problem.  An order will have many statuses in the order_order_status table at the same time.  The current status is the newest row in the order_order_status table.  Your solution will return all orders which have had the status 'Quote' (for example) at any time, not just the orders with 'Quote' as the current status.

Comment: An order can have many statuses at the same time. -- How it is possible , please edit your Question

Comment: Comment edited.  See the example data in the question.  Order id 2 has 12 separate status changes, but the CURRENT status is 'Closed' (id=10)

Comment: so you want to get only single order by order id with order status ?

Comment: No.  If I ask for all orders with status 'Quote' order ID 2 should not be returned.  Order ID 2 should only be returned if I ask for all orders with status "Closed".

Comment: yes , that means you want to pass two variables : orderstatus and order id , am i right ?

Comment: Not quite.  There are thousands of orders in the database.  I want to be able to say "Give me all orders which have the CURRENT status of 'Quote'".  The table of orders returned would not include order id 2 because it has a current status of "Closed".

Comment: brother , please decide what do you want to get , please write query

Comment: please display me table results , what do you want in output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173730/discussion-between-mp035-and-saurabh-mistry).